# How to specify that threads should not outlive the function they were created in?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to solve the toy problem of finding the longest string in a slice, in parallel. But I ran into the following compiler error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due
to conflicting requirements
  --> main.rs:10:33
   |
10 |     for assigned_lines in input.chunks(max_lines_per_worker as usize) {
   |                                 ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1
defined on the body at 5:59...
  --> main.rs:5:60
   |
5  | pub fn max_length(input: &[&str], workers: usize) -> usize {
   |                                                            ^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> main.rs:10:27
   |
10 |     for assigned_lines in input.chunks(max_lines_per_worker as usize) {
   |                           ^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@main.rs:11:36: 19:10 assigned_lines:&[&str]]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> main.rs:11:22
   |
11 |         let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I understand correctly, the compiler is complaining because it can't figure out that the threads (and thus the closed over values) should not live beyond the end of this function. I need to tell it that somehow, probably by specifying a lifetime?. I don't know what to put the lifetime specifier(s) onto, and there doesn't seem to be some kind of special `'this_function` lifetime, so I'm not sure what (say) marking `handles` and each individual `handle` with the same lifetime would do to solve the problem.

Here's the code that produced the error message.

```
use std::thread;
use std::cmp::max;

pub fn max_length(input: &[&str], workers: usize) -> usize {
    let mut result = 0;
    let max_lines_per_worker = (input.len() as f32 / workers as f32).ceil();
    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for assigned_lines in input.chunks(max_lines_per_worker as usize) {
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut count = 0;

            for line in assigned_lines {
                count = max(count, line.len())
            }

            count
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        if let Ok(count) = handle.join() {
            result = max(result, count);
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", max_length(&LINES, 3));
}

const LINES: [&'static str; 4] = ["abc", "123", "qwerty", "zxcvbnm"];
```

Comment: The Rust term for such a thread is a "scoped" thread. There is no way to do this in the standard library, but multiple crates provide the functionality. The linked duplicate discusses some of them.

Comment: Ah, that's the phrase I should have been searching for. I managed to get a version of the above code working using [crossbeam](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam) after a minimum of fuss.